# How to sort Grid columns in Vaadin 23

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin23

We migrated from vaadin 8 to 23 and had to change the class com.vaadin.ui.Grid to com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid.

Implementation changed for column sorting.

I added column using below code and expected Grid sorting to work. I see the sort icons but the list is not sorting.

```
addColumn(Class::getName)
    .setSortable(true)
    .setHeader("Column Name")
    .setId("name-column-name");
```

Explicitly specified the sortable flag as default value is false.

However, on debugging I found that the payload

```
{
            "type": "publishedEventHandler",
            "node": 7,
            "templateEventMethodName": "sortersChanged",
            "templateEventMethodArgs": [
                [
                    {
                        "path": "col0",
                        "direction": "desc"
                    }
                ]
            ],
            "promise": 4
        }
```

On Debuging through the vaadin classes, I found that the method **hasListener** below is returning a false.

```
public boolean hasListener(Class<? extends ComponentEvent> eventType) {
        if (eventType == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Event type cannot be null");
        }
        return componentEventData.containsKey(eventType);
    }
```

The event name which is triggered is
*class com.vaadin.flow.data.event.SortEvent*
However list had following events

```
class com.vaadin.flow.data.selection.SingleSelectionEvent
class com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.dnd.GridDragStartEvent
class com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.dnd.GridDragEndEvent
```

I think this is the reason why my grid is not sorting. Anyone who can help here?

Comment: Can you show how you set the items to the grid (call of setItems)

Comment: ```MyDataProvider myDataProvider = new MyDataProvider(myDataService);
        this.myDataProvider = myDataProvider.withConfigurableFilter();
        myGridComponent.setItems(myDataProvider);```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you're using a lazy-loading DataProvider for the Grid. In that case, you need to set up a sort property in your columns:

```
grid.addColumn(...).setSortable(true).setSortProperty("sort-property");
```

The set of sort properties will be available from the `Query` object in the DataProvider and it's up to the DataProvider implementation and the backend service to sort the data based on each property and sort direction (ascending / descending).

More information and examples in the docs: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/data-provider#data-binding.data-provider.lazy-sorting